# Why does my online contact form produce a Warning and Fatal Error when after sending utilising my host's relay, but not with Google's?

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I have recently migrated a web form online after testing in XAMPP using a Google SMTP relay and Swiftmailer.  There has been absolutely no problems with the Google relay utilising my own inbox, however, when trying to switch to my hosting provider's (Siteground) recommended relay and instructions, also utilising a domain based email, my form is hanging on send, and I receive the following:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.sgcpanel.com' did not match expected CN=`uk2.siteground.eu' in /home/tho/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 95

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Unable to connect with TLS encryption' in /home/tho/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php:289 Stack trace: #0 /home/tho/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(118): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() #1 /home/tho/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #2 /home/tho/public_html/sendmessage.php(30): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #3 {main} thrown in /home/tho/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php on line 289
```

Note that the email account itself is working perfectly.  It is set up in Mac Mail, and sends and receives with no issues at all.

My hosting provider is trying, but I don't think they can understand what issue I'm having.  I've ended up narrowing it down to the transport function.  See my code from the PHP below:

Google (which works as expected):

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls')
        ->setUsername('foobar@googlemail.com')
        ->setPassword('APP GENERATED PASSWORD');
```

Hosting Provider (which does not work as expected):

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('uk2.siteground.eu', 25, 'tls')
    ->setUsername('email@mydomain.com')
    ->setPassword('MY EMAIL PASSWORD');
```

The code seems ok to me, as it's only swapping out details.  These were the settings provided by Siteground.

I've so far tried the following:

- Changed the ports between 2525, 25, 587, and 465 without success;
- Switched between TLS and SSL without success;
- Changed my password trying various combinations without special
  characters with no success;
- Tried a Google search for all the permutations of 'Swiftmailer Siteground SMTP etc' but nothing has arisen.
- Updated Swiftmailer to the latest version server side with no success;

I have raised further tickets, and they have updated the PHP server side for me.  This now does not show an error, but just the number zero (ie. '0').  Also email is not being sent, but this is a separate issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by my host.  They made some alterations to the PHP server side.  At first there was no success, but after waiting an hour or so, this sorted the issue.

Well, maybe not sorted in an ideal sense, but at least as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems that the SSL certificate on the server uk2.siteground.eu does not include the correct hostname for the server, rather a wildcard for sgcpanel.com. The certificate on 587 it does not contain uk2.siteground.eu as a valid name for the server.

If you are using php 5.6 they changed the default to verify peer and peer names for certificates.

The proper fix would be for Siteground to add correct certificates to the server. You might override the checks with the newest version of SwiftMailer on github it seems.

The setStreamOptions added in september might solve your problems, but reduce security a bit by not checking if it is the correct server it is communicating with.

I'm not able to test it at the moment, but try:

```
$ssl_options = array(
   'ssl'         => array(
      'verify_peer'       => false,
      'verfify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
);
$transport->setStreamOptions($ssl_options);
```

Or the array might be

```
$ssl_options = array(
   'verify_peer'       => false,
   'verfify_peer_name' => false,
);
$transport->setStreamOptions($ssl_options);
```

More info:

http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/571

Comment: The host server uses PHP 5.5.30 so I'm not sure how that affects me with regards to this.

Comment: The certificate on the server is still wrong, so you might want to disable the verification anyway if the service provider can't/won't set up their certificate correctly. The certificate presented does not contain uk2.siteground.eu in common names or alternative names so software should reject it. Maybe they have another name for the server ending with sgcpanel.com you could use. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=uk2.siteground.eu (this is for 443, but they present the same on 587)

Comment: On my php 5.5.30 (OS X 10.11.2) I can connect on port 587 without certificate error, but get authentication error naturally, with a simple file. 
`require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('uk2.siteground.eu', 587, 'tls')
    ->setUsername('email@mydomain.com')
    ->setPassword('MY EMAIL PASSWORD');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('test')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('me@domain.org' => 'A test'))
  ->setBody('Hello')
  ;

$result = $mailer->send($message);`

Comment: I amended my post above.  They updated the PHP for me server side, but I am still getting issues unfortunately, now with sending email too.